# Orbeon uses <div class="row">. Can I change it to use <div class="row-fluid"> to match Liferay?

Tags: orbeon

I am using Orbeon 4.7.1 with the proxy-portlet. I'm using CSS to hide the form title and description. However, there is stil empty space left at the top. This appears to be a conflict with Liferay which puts `<div class="row-fluid">` around the orbeon form.

It looks like changing Orbeon to use `"row-fluid"` instead of `"row"` might solve this issue. Is this configurable in orbeon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form source, add the `fluid` attribute:

```
<fr:view fluid="true">
```

This causes `row-fluid` classes to appear.